# Eval command is throwing logs on console-How to suppress it?

Tags: shell, unix

In a for loop i used eval statement. But it is throwing logs on console for non matching patterns.
I tried redirecting the eval cmd o/p to null as below.But its not working.

for loop ..
do
..
temp=`eval "$tempVal"` >/dev/null 2>&1
..
done

Any other way to handle this? 
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: & prefer not to use eval, unless it's the only way or you completely trust the variable contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be attempting redirection after assigning `eval` output to a variable.  You need to say:

```
temp=`eval "$tempVal" 2>/dev/null`
```

instead.  Moreover, consider using `$(...)` instead of backticks:

```
temp=$(eval "$tempVal" 2>/dev/null)
```